# How to show RSS feed custom things in HTML page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, rss

I need to parse the RSS-Feed(XML version2.0) using XML and I want to display the parsed detail in HTML page, I tried in many ways.But its not working.

I want to show Feed title, description (characters limit), image, date and time etc.. The data will scroll up or down. Auto refresh after some seconds. Please don't suggest me the sites. I know the site name but I want to make it manually.

I am using this script

```js
function parseRSS(url, container) {
  $.ajax({
    url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=20&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      //console.log(data.responseData.feed);
      $(container).html('<h1>'+capitaliseFirstLetter(data.responseData.feed.title)+'</h1>');

      $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function(key, value){
        var thehtml = '<h2><a href="'+value.link+'" target="_blank">'+value.title+'</a></h2>';
        $(container).append(thehtml);
      });
    }
  });
}
```